# Remove coffee stains

Tags: cleaning, clothing, laundry

Today I spilled some coffee on my white formal shirt. I tried to wash off the portion with water, soaked the part of shirt in milk(crazy isn't it).. But these two options didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I use German powder BioStein (using it for years):
http://shop.biostein.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

Use a small amount of vinegar to remove the stain.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried using vinegar, but it didn't work.

Comment: did u let it sit for sometime? You have to let it sit for sometime after you apply.

Comment: I just left it for 5 mins. I will let it sit overnight and see if it works.

Comment: Chlorine bleach should lighten the stain, but test it on an inconspicuous are of the shirt first (bleach can dissolve come fabrics!).

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you could try :

1. Salt
2. Baking soda
3. Dedicated product (Cillit, ...)
4. Bleach. be carefull though as it might "burn" the fabric and leave an unremovable stain

I would try in this order, the 2 last having some risk of making it worse : a stain that you just can't remove...

Comment: Can you please add some details on how to use salt or baking soda, for example?